# How do I add an ASP.NET control inside an ASCX to an external RequiredFieldValidator programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, user-controls, ascx

I have a drop-down list inside a user control (ASCX) that I want to validate from the page on which I've placed the ASCX, but when I set the ControlToValidate to the drop-down list the page complains that it can't be found. Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Don't you mean ControlToValidate, not AssociatedControlID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expose the dropdown list with a public property in your user control:

```
public DropDownList DropDownToValidate
    {
        get
        {
            return ddlTest;
        }
    }
```

Then use the UniqueID of the exposed Dropdown to set the control to validate in the page load of the page on which you dropped the user control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RequiredFieldValidator1.ControlToValidate = WebUserControl1.DropDownToValidate.UniqueID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get it to work for a user control nested within a user control, but I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: We're now 8.5 years on but this solution isn't working for me. I'm getting `Unable to find control id 'ctl00$MainContent$TextFieldIdentifier$TB' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'TextFieldIdentifierValidator'.` if I do the wireup.  Wiring up on `Page_Load()`.

Comment: Are you adding the user control to the main page dynamically?  Maybe try moving the set control to validate to the Page_PreRender or maybe on a control on load handler set on the page.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to do this is to do this in your user control class:

```
[ValidationProperty("Foo")]
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
     public string Foo
     {
          get { return(yourDropDown.SelectedValue); }
     }
}
```

And then in the page you place the user control on:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="yourUserControlName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You are required to make a selection" />
```

Not *quite* the same thing, but that's the only workaround that I know.

Comment: This one worked for me, however it does a postback before it validates which is unlike the other RequiredFieldValidators that are validating the regular textboxes, any suggestions on getting them to work all at the same time.

Comment: Did you Chris Mullins's answer and expose the whole dropdown instead of just the SelectedValue?  Other than that, you may have to write some custom javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to validate user control is to have public method inside your user control:

```
public void Validate() {
  reqRecipientName.Validate();
  reqRecipientMail.Validate();
  valRecipientMail.Validate();
  reqRecipientPhone.Validate();
}
```

where `reqRecipientName`, `reqRecipientMail`... are ID of validators (they are also insice ascx).
And then on Page inside submit method call `controlId.Validate();`
This works for me.